# Compensation for delays in Malaga to Madrid flight causing missed flight to Sao Paulo (and then Río)?

Tags: compensation, delays

My flight from Malaga to Madrid was delayed more than 3 hours and I missed the connecting flight from Madrid to Sao Paulo. We had a 24 hr layover at Madrid. The following evening our Madrid to Sao Paulo flight was delayed for more than 4 hours causing our next flight connection to be missed from Sao Paulo to Río.

Surely due to any or all of these flight delays we are entitled to some compensation? Instead of arriving to Río on a Wednesday morning we arrived on a Friday evening

Comment: I suppose all flights were on the same ticket, but can you confirm that? What was the cause of the delay of the first flight?

Comment: Also I’m not sure how you could have been delayed from Wednesday morning to Friday evening? There are over 20 flights a day between São Paulo and Rio, so at worst you should have been in Rio on Thursday around noon or early afternoon. Can you please give details of the original itinerary (flights and dates) and what you ended up flying?

Comment: I do not if you did, in any case: if you see a risk to miss s flight, contact staff as early as you can. They could move you to an other flight (they cannot move an entire plane, but few passengers yes), or to an other destination (they may find it is cheaper for them to pay an other airline instead of hotels and compensation (maybe to flight you via Lisbon). In any case: start contacting the airline: they will say "no" on first contact (and BTW document both mails with dates), but so you started the process.

Answer (score 3):

Since you were departing from the EU, **provided all three flights were on a single booking**, EC261 gives you the right to:

- Assistance: rebooking on the first available flight, paying for hotels and transfers to/from hotels for any night you were stranded, paying for meals and refreshments… This always applies, but there are conditions.
- Compensation: this applies unless there were extraordinary circumstances. So for instance if the aircraft had a fault or a crew member was sick, you are owed compensation. If there was a huge storm that affected all/most flights in the area, you are not. The classification of what counts as extraordinary circumstances is complex and still evolving (and is the subject of many conflicts with airlines).

You can find more details on the official EU site in this topic: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm

Note that it is also an obligation for the carrier to inform you about your rights.

There’s also a right to a refund and/or return to the origin if you had wanted to cancel your plans, but this doesn’t look like it’s relevant here.